# Apply navigation <li> classes to child <a> anchors, Wordpress nav

Tags: wordpress, list, class, navigation, anchor

I would like to change the standard navigation on a Wordpress site from

```
<ul>
   <li class='active'><a></a></li>
</ul>
```

to be:

```
<nav>
  <a class='active'></a>
<nav>
```

I have managed to wrap with a nav element and remove both the ul and li tags, but I still want the 'active' class to be added but to the anchor.

This is what I currently have:

```
$menu = wp_nav_menu( array( 
            'theme_location' => 'primary',
            'container' => 'nav',
            'echo' => false
        ) ); 

echo strip_tags($menu, '<nav><a>');
```

I can do this with JS but I want to use PHP and do everything on the back end.

Comment: take a look: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/remove-li-elements-from-output-of-wp_nav_menu/

Answer (score 0):

After digging around I discovered the following code fix:

```
$cleanernav = wp_nav_menu(array(
                'menu' => 'Main Nav Menu',
                'container' => 'nav',
                'items_wrap' => '%3$s', 
                'echo' => false,
                )
            );

            $find = array('<ul>', '><a', 'li');
            $replace = array('','','a');

            echo str_replace($find, $replace, $cleanernav);
```

This is a modified version of Zoe Rooney's solution http://zoerooney.com/blog/tutorials/removing-list-items-wordpress-menus/

It builds on this to also remove the ul element providing a cleaner

```
<nav>
    <a class='xyz'></a>
    <a class='xyz'></a>
    <a class='xyz'></a>
    <a class='xyz'></a>
</nav>
```